# Integral $\int \sqrt{1-b(1-\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}})^{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm working on my physics homework and encounter such the integral. I have no idea how to deal with this. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Well, WolframAlpha gives back a mess of elliptic integrals and complex numbers, so unless you just want to calculate a specific *definite* integral, I suggest you numerically approximate.

Comment: Is $b>0$ ? Are you sure that it is not a definite integral ? Being a physicist, I strongly suspect that it is the case. Please, clarify. Cheers :-)

Comment: I'm dealing with the problem that use WKB approximation to calculate the tunneling frequency of symmetric double potential well. The potential is $V_{0}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}})^{2}$. As a beginner, I'm unsure if my understanding right. But I think the integral $\int \sqrt{2m(E-V_{0}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}})^{2})}dx$ is required for WKB approximation.

Comment: Bear in mind WKB is already an approximation anyway, so an approximate treatment of the definite integral it obtains will serve physicists' needs. (It's definite because we want the probability amplitude for tunneling, say from $x=x_1$ to $x=x_2$.)